# Can regular expressions be used for the substitution in sympy?

Tags: python, regex, sympy

Suppose I have a symbolic calculation in `sympy`, that modifies basic arithmetic operations on numbers by adding errors to them:

```
from sympy import * 

p0,p1,p2 = symbols("p0:3")
ep0,ep1,ep2 = symbols("ep0:3")
x0,x1,x2 = symbols("x0:3")
ex0,ex1,ex2 = symbols("ex0:3")
q0,q1,q2 = symbols("q0:3")
eq0,eq1,eq2 = symbols("eq0:3")
r0,r1,r2 = symbols("r0:3")
er0,er1,er2 = symbols("er0:3")
n0,n1,n2 = symbols("n0:3")
en0,en1,en2 = symbols("en0:3")

p = Matrix([p0,p1,p2])
x = Matrix([x0,x1,x2])
q = Matrix([q0,q1,q2])
r = Matrix([r0,r1,r2])
n = Matrix([n0,n1,n2])

errors = []

def fl_op(a,b,op,e):
    return op(a,b)*(1 + e)

def fl_add(a,b):
    # Append an addition error to the global list of errors
    errors.append(symbols("err_add" + str(len(errors)+1)))
    return fl_op(a,b, lambda x,y : x + y, errors[-1]) 

def fl_sub(a,b):
    # Append an addition error to the global list of errors
    errors.append(symbols("err_sub" + str(len(errors)+1)))
    return fl_op(a,b, lambda x,y : x - y, errors[-1]) 

def fl_mul(a,b):
    # Append an addition error to the global list of errors
    errors.append(symbols("err_mul" + str(len(errors)+1)))
    return fl_op(a,b, lambda x,y : x * y, errors[-1]) 

def fl_div(a,b):
    # Append an addition error to the global list of errors
    errors.append(symbols("err_div" + str(len(errors)+1)))
    return fl_op(a,b, lambda x,y : x / y, errors[-1]) 

def fl_vsub(va,vb):
    assert (len(va) == len(vb))
    return [fl_sub(va[i],vb[i]) for i in range(len(va))]

def fl_vadd(va,vb):
    assert (len(va) == len(vb))
    return [fl_add(va[i],vb[i]) for i in range(len(va))]

def fl_vsum(va):
    return fl_add(fl_add(va[0],va[1]),va[2])

def fl_dot(va,vb):
    assert (len(va) == len(vb))
    return fl_vsum([fl_mul(va[i],vb[i]) for i in range(len(va))])

dotSub  = fl_sub(fl_dot(r,n), fl_dot(p,n))
dotSub = simplify(dotSub)
vSubDot = fl_dot(fl_vsub(r,p),n)
vSubDot = simplify(vSubDot)
```

print(expand(dotSub))

The result of the print statement is this:

> -err_add10*err_add9*err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 - err_add10*err_add9*err_mul6*n0*p0 -
>   err_add10*err_add9*err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_add10*err_add9*err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_add9*err_sub11*n0*p0
>   - err_add10*err_add9*err_sub11*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_add9*n0*p0 - err_add10*err_add9*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add10*err_mul6*n0*p0 - err_add10*err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_add10*err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_mul8*err_sub11*n2*p2 -
>   err_add10*err_mul8*n2*p2 - err_add10*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add10*err_sub11*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_sub11*n2*p2 -
>   err_add10*n0*p0 - err_add10*n1*p1 - err_add10*n2*p2 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul1*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul2*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_add5*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_sub11*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_add5*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_mul1*n0*r0 + err_add4*err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_add4*err_mul2*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_sub11*n1*r1 + err_add4*n0*r0 + err_add4*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 + err_add5*err_mul1*n0*r0 +
>   err_add5*err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 + err_add5*err_mul2*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*err_mul3*err_sub11*n2*r2 + err_add5*err_mul3*n2*r2 +
>   err_add5*err_sub11*n0*r0 + err_add5*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*err_sub11*n2*r2 + err_add5*n0*r0 + err_add5*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*n2*r2 - err_add9*err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add9*err_mul6*n0*p0 - err_add9*err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_add9*err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_add9*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add9*err_sub11*n1*p1 - err_add9*n0*p0 - err_add9*n1*p1 +
>   err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 + err_mul1*n0*r0 + err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_mul2*n1*r1 + err_mul3*err_sub11*n2*r2 + err_mul3*n2*r2 -
>   err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 - err_mul6*n0*p0 - err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_mul8*err_sub11*n2*p2 - err_mul8*n2*p2 -
>   err_sub11*n0*p0 + err_sub11*n0*r0 - err_sub11*n1*p1 + err_sub11*n1*r1
>   - err_sub11*n2*p2 + err_sub11*n2*r2 - n0*p0 + n0*r0 - n1*p1 + n1*r1 - n2*p2 + n2*r2

All the `err_` terms are different from each other, but their products can be ignored. What is the best way to do this? Can the `subs` function in `sympy` accept something like a rule for the product of all `err_` terms that makes the product equal to 0? Is it possible to overload the arithmetic `*` operator for the sympy symbols to check if the name of both product operands starts with `err_`, and result with a symbolic 0?

Specifying all possible combinations for the products of the `err_` terms quickly becomes impossible, because the number of combinations grows extremely fast.

Maybe it would be easier if the string is parsed using `python.regex` to exclude all products. How would this work?

I have tried the following python `regex`, but it has no effect on the string:

```
import regex
dotSubStr = str(expand(dotSub))
re.sub("[+,-,\s]err_*\*err_*\s",'', dotSubStr)
```

Picking up a first product works with

```
re.sub("err_(add|sub|mul|div)\d+\*err_(add|sub|mul|div)\d+",'', dotSubStr)
```

> '-**n0*p0 - *err_mul6*n0*p0 - **n1*p1 - *err_mul7*n1*p1 -
>   *err_sub11*n0*p0 - *err_sub11*n1*p1 - *n0*p0 - *n1*p1 - *err_sub11*n0*p0 - *n0*p0 - *err_sub11*n1*p1 - *n1*p1 - *err_sub11*n2*p2 - *n2*p2 - *n0*p0 - *n1*p1 - *n2*p2 - err_add10*n0*p0 - err_add10*n1*p1 - err_add10*n2*p2 + **n0*r0 + *err_mul1*n0*r0 + **n1*r1 + *err_mul2*n1*r1 + *err_sub11*n0*r0 + *err_sub11*n1*r1 + *n0*r0 + *n1*r1 + *err_sub11*n0*r0 + *n0*r0 + *err_sub11*n1*r1 + *n1*r1 + *n0*r0 + *n1*r1 + err_add4*n0*r0 + err_add4*n1*r1 + *err_sub11*n0*r0 + *n0*r0 + *err_sub11*n1*r1 + *n1*r1 + *err_sub11*n2*r2 + *n2*r2 + *n0*r0 + *n1*r1 + *n2*r2 + err_add5*n0*r0 + err_add5*n1*r1 + err_add5*n2*r2 - *err_sub11*n0*p0 - *n0*p0 - *err_sub11*n1*p1 - *n1*p1 - *n0*p0 - *n1*p1 - err_add9*n0*p0 - err_add9*n1*p1 + *n0*r0 + err_mul1*n0*r0 + *n1*r1 + err_mul2*n1*r1 +
>   *n2*r2 + err_mul3*n2*r2 - *n0*p0 - err_mul6*n0*p0 - *n1*p1 - err_mul7*n1*p1 - *n2*p2 - err_mul8*n2*p2 - err_sub11*n0*p0 +
>   err_sub11*n0*r0 - err_sub11*n1*p1 + err_sub11*n1*r1 - err_sub11*n2*p2
>   + err_sub11*n2*r2 - n0*p0 + n0*r0 - n1*p1 + n1*r1 - n2*p2 + n2*r2'

So this removes the product if the expresion has maximally 3 product operands, but leaves whatever is after the product intact, and it should also be removed.

Comment: Try `\w+\d+` after `err_` instead of `*`; also, `[+, -, \s]` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: tried it, it doesn't work. I wanted to use `*` to make it glob everything up to the next whitespace `\s`, so that multiple products are picked up as well. Checked `[+,-,\s]` and converted it to `[+-]`, thanks.

Comment: Can the suffixes of `err_` variables take any other form, e.g. with more underscores or different ordering of numbers / letters?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog their form is `err_(add|mult|sub|div)\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to filter the products using `regex` so I'll answer in case someone needs this.

From the starting string with arithmetic expressions:

> -err_add10*err_add9*err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 - err_add10*err_add9*err_mul6*n0*p0 -
>   err_add10*err_add9*err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_add10*err_add9*err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_add9*err_sub11*n0*p0
>   - err_add10*err_add9*err_sub11*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_add9*n0*p0 - err_add10*err_add9*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add10*err_mul6*n0*p0 - err_add10*err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_add10*err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_mul8*err_sub11*n2*p2 -
>   err_add10*err_mul8*n2*p2 - err_add10*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add10*err_sub11*n1*p1 - err_add10*err_sub11*n2*p2 -
>   err_add10*n0*p0 - err_add10*n1*p1 - err_add10*n2*p2 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul1*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_mul2*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_add5*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*err_sub11*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_add5*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_add5*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_mul1*n0*r0 + err_add4*err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_add4*err_mul2*n1*r1 + err_add4*err_sub11*n0*r0 +
>   err_add4*err_sub11*n1*r1 + err_add4*n0*r0 + err_add4*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 + err_add5*err_mul1*n0*r0 +
>   err_add5*err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 + err_add5*err_mul2*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*err_mul3*err_sub11*n2*r2 + err_add5*err_mul3*n2*r2 +
>   err_add5*err_sub11*n0*r0 + err_add5*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*err_sub11*n2*r2 + err_add5*n0*r0 + err_add5*n1*r1 +
>   err_add5*n2*r2 - err_add9*err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add9*err_mul6*n0*p0 - err_add9*err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_add9*err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_add9*err_sub11*n0*p0 -
>   err_add9*err_sub11*n1*p1 - err_add9*n0*p0 - err_add9*n1*p1 +
>   err_mul1*err_sub11*n0*r0 + err_mul1*n0*r0 + err_mul2*err_sub11*n1*r1 +
>   err_mul2*n1*r1 + err_mul3*err_sub11*n2*r2 + err_mul3*n2*r2 -
>   err_mul6*err_sub11*n0*p0 - err_mul6*n0*p0 - err_mul7*err_sub11*n1*p1 -
>   err_mul7*n1*p1 - err_mul8*err_sub11*n2*p2 - err_mul8*n2*p2 -
>   err_sub11*n0*p0 + err_sub11*n0*r0 - err_sub11*n1*p1 + err_sub11*n1*r1
>   - err_sub11*n2*p2 + err_sub11*n2*r2 - n0*p0 + n0*r0 - n1*p1 + n1*r1 - n2*p2 + n2*r2

`regex` can be used like this to remove all multiple products of the `err_*` terms:

```
import re
dotSubFinal = re.sub("(err_(add|sub|mul|div)\d+\*){2,}",'del', dotSubStr)
dotSubFinal = re.sub("[+-]\s*del[npr]\d\*[npr]\d",'', dotSubFinal)
dotSubFinal = re.sub("\s{2,}",'', dotSubFinal)
```

resulting in :

print(dotSubFinal)

> -err_add10*n0*p0 - err_add10*n1*p1 - err_add10*n2*p2+ err_add4*n0*r0+err_add4*n1*r1+ err_add5*n0*r0 + err_add5*n1*r1 + err_add5*n2*r2 err_add9*n0*p0 - 
>   err_add9*n1*p1+ err_mul1*n0*r0+ err_mul2*n1*r1+
>   err_mul3*n2*r2- err_mul6*n0*p0- err_mul7*n1*p1- err_mul8*n2*p2 -
>   err_sub11*n0*p0 + err_sub11*n0*r0 - err_sub11*n1*p1 + err_sub11*n1*r1
>   - err_sub11*n2*p2 + err_sub11*n2*r2 - n0*p0 + n0*r0 - n1*p1 + n1*r1 - n2*p2 + n2*r2

Comment: So you intended leave a single `err_` variable where there was a product of them?

Comment: The intention is to leave a single `err_` where there is only a single `err_` in the product with other operands. `err_` multiplying anything but `err_` is different than 0. `err_` multiplying `err_` is zero and the rest of the product is then zero.